# I'm trying to render template of html file using Flask, however, i get the same error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template/index.html

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to render the template of index.html using Flask.
I get an error that the file is not found. The error is jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template/index.html. The file exists in the templates folder and it has the name index.html

```
`from flask import Flask, render_template



app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("template/index.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)`

I have already tried creating a directory called templates and putting the html file there - as suggested to some users here
I also tried changing the name of the files and the directory (template and templates)
I have tried importing jinja2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `template/` prefix from `render_template` argument. You already specified, that templates will be located in template folder, so you need to supply only the filename of the template to the `render_template` function.

This will work if there is a template named `index.html` in `template` folder.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template



app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```